# x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa:...authority certificate "osmacbook")

Tags: docker, kubernetes, certificate, x509certificate, x509

I was working on a project and learning docker with Kubernetes, and my containers keep showing up even when I tried to kill / remove / purge all of them. So I tried uninstall Docker and Minikube from my Mac, and also errased some folders from my Finder, such as /minikube, /docker and maybe one more. I reinstalled both and now when I try to use it with "docker ps" or "docker build..." it returns:

"x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "osmacbook")"

Recently I have also changed my MacBook name from "osmacbook" to "ols".

Anyone can help me please?

Comment: Please provide information how did you install Docker, Kubernetes, etc. It was tutorial or official docs? Did you use some own configuration YAMLs? Also could you provide whole error output?

Comment: Do you still have this problem ?
Are you using [Docker Desktop for Mac](https://hub.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-mac/)  ? 
Which docker version do you have ?
Can you answer @PjoterS's questions ?

Comment: No @matt_j, thanks! Already solved

Comment: That's great :) Can you describe how you solved the problem and what was the cause ?
It may be helpful for other members of the community.

Answer (score 0):

This error message means that you do not have a trusted certificate, such as the default self-signed certificate

might be able to assist better if you could post your  docker-info command output

Another approach is to skip tls verification for your environment; check [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/) documentation on DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY variable